# Parsing JSON within jQuery document

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jQuery function that takes a JSON file as input. I need to move the JSON data into the same jQuery file. Apologies for my limited knowledge of working with JSON. I'm sure this is a simple fix.

Here's the code I have now. This code works perfectly:

```
$.getJSON('assets/images.json', function(data) {
    var item = data.images[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.images.length)];
    $('.tile-wrap .left').css({'background': 'url(assets/' + item.image + ')' + 'no-repeat center center'});
    $('<p>' + item.caption + '</p>').appendTo('.caption');
});
```

As you can see, the snippet references a JSON file with .getJSON. As I said before, I'd like to move the JSON data into the same script.

Here's what I've tried, but doesn't seem to work:

```
    var imagedata = {
        "images": [{
            "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
            "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }, {
            "image": "group.jpg",
            "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }, {
            "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
            "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }, {
            "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
            "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }]
    };

$.parseJSON(imagedata, function(data) {
    var item = data.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.images.length)];
    $('.tile-wrap .left').css({
        'background': 'url(assets/' + item.image + ')' + 'no-repeat center center'
    });
    $('<p>' + item.caption + '</p>').appendTo('.caption');
});
```

As I said, this is probably an easy fix so apologies for my limited JSON knowledge.

Comment: The JSON should be in the string format. When you parse it using `.parseJSON()` it will return the Object representation.

Comment: You don't need the JSON in string format if it will be on the same script file. Just declare a var with its content. This way you don't have to use the parseJSON method.

Comment: @Callebe I agree, but my comment is pertinent to the code as it has been posted by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer need to deal with JSON at all as you now have an object literal and not a JSON string.

Just get rid of `getJSON` and `parseJSON` entirely and replace `data` wherever it is used with `imagedata`.

```
var imagedata = {
    "images": [{
        "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
        "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    }, {
        "image": "group.jpg",
        "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    }, {
        "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
        "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    }, {
        "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
        "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    }]
};

var item = imagedata.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagedata.images.length)];
$('.tile-wrap .left').css({
    'background': 'url(assets/' + item.image + ')' + 'no-repeat center center'
});
$('<p>' + item.caption + '</p>').appendTo('.caption');
```

If this is actually what the json looks like, you could even simplify it and just have an `images` array without the `imagedata` wrapper object.  As follows:

```
var images =[{
    "image": "hero-bg.jpg",
    "caption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
}, {
/* ... */  
}];

var item = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
$('.tile-wrap .left').css({
    'background': 'url(assets/' + item.image + ')' + 'no-repeat center center'
});
$('<p>' + item.caption + '</p>').appendTo('.caption');
```

Comment: @Andy Either one really, but I'll make that clearer.

Comment: Great that worked! I knew the solution was something simpler than what I was trying to do.